# Connect cassandra and java

Tags: java, cassandra

I am new to cassandra and I want to connect to cassandra with java jdbc.I use the code below and get this error message...

```
try {
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  System.out.println(con);
} catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_cql_version(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.(CassandraConnection.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:92)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)  at
>   connect.Connect.main(Connect.java:24)

also I use these jars:

- hector-core-1.1-2
- libthrift-0.6.1.jar
- cassandra-jdbc-1.2.1.jar
- cassandra-all-0.7.0.jar

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You'll need the cql jar as well. Can download it from the Apache site.

Comment: What looks to me reason behind this error is multiple Cassandra thrift jar versions in classpath. This is something "Cassandra$Client.set_cql_version" introduced in Cassandra 1.2 but not available in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably facing the version mismatch issue as mentioned by Anse Danesh. For working with Cassandra from with in Java, I would recommend using the DataStax Cassandra java driver
https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

Its really easy to work with and is properly maintained by the DataStax community.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a version mismatch between the JDBC jar and the other Cassandra jars.

Comment: thanks in advance.. I am new, so you mean all jar files should be the same version?

Comment: Not necessarily - I don't know anything about cassandra-jdbc or cassandra-all, or even cassandra drivers in general. But the error message you are seeing is because `org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection` is attempting to call a method on `org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client` that doesn't exist in your environment. This happens when Class A is compiled against one version of Class B (that method had to exist at compile-time or else the compilation would fail) but Class B in the deployed environment does not have that method, meaning that there is a version mismatch.

Comment: So the best answer is to figure out exactly what version of `cassandra-all` that `cassandra-jdbc-1.2.1` is meant to work with.